# Updating database records with unique constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, unique-constraint

Given the following simple table structure (SQL Server 2008), I want to be able to maintain uniqueness of my numerical sequence column, but I want to be able to update that value for any given record(s).

```
CREATE TABLE MYLIST(
      ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
    , TITLE varchar(50) NOT NULL
    , SEQUENCE int NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT pk_mylist_id PRIMARY KEY(ID)
    , CONSTRAINT uq_mylist_sequence UNIQUE(SEQUENCE)
);
```

My interface allows me to jumble up the order of the items and **I will know prior to doing the update which non-overlapping sequence they should all be in**, but how do I perform the update without being confronted with a violation of the unique constraint?

For instance, say I have these records:

```
ID  TITLE   SEQUENCE
1   APPLE   1
2   BANANA  2
3   CHERRY  3
```

And I want to update their sequence numbers to the following:

```
ID  TITLE   SEQUENCE
1   APPLE   3
2   BANANA  1
3   CHERRY  2
```

But really I could be dealing with a couple dozen items. The sequence numbers must not overlap. I've thought about trying to use triggers or temporarily disabling the constraint, but that would seem to create more issues. I am using C# and LINQ-to-SQL, but am open to strictly database solutions.

Comment: Can you update in one statement?

Comment: I have the freedom to try just about anything if that answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign them the *negative* of their correct value, then after all updates have occurred, do a final update where you set `SEQUENCE = -SEQUENCE`.

It is *not* very efficient, but since you say you only have a couple dozen items, I doubt the impact would be noticeable. I am also assuming that you can use negative numbers as "magic values" to indicate temporarily mis-assigned values.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this and actually thought of it myself a few minutes after posting the question. For my situation, this may make the most sense.

Comment: Hmmm... there's nothing stopping someone from entering a negative number directly into the database, which would break this solution.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious way is to write as one batch. Internally, SQL will defer the constraint checks so intermediate uniqueness is irrelevant.

Writing row by row does not make sense and causes the problem you have.

You can change this to write into a temp table, and then "flush" the results at the end, even check uniqueness over the temp table first.

```
DECLARE @NewSeq TABLE (ID int, NewSeq int)

INSERT @NewSeq (ID, NewSeq) VALUES (1, 3)
INSERT @NewSeq (ID, NewSeq) VALUES (2, 1)
INSERT @NewSeq (ID, NewSeq) VALUES (3, 2)

UPDATE
   M
SET
   SEQUENCE = NewSeq
FROM
   MYLIST M
   JOIN
   @NewSeq N ON M.ID = N.ID
```

Comment: This seems to be the technically-correct solution with the least chance of error, though it would require additional code. For my purposes, Dave's negative number trick is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to follow that workflow of inserting without knowing the right order and then having to come back with an update later to set the right order, I'd say your best option is to get rid of the unique constraint because it is causing you more problems than it is worth.  Of course, only you know how much that unique constraint is "worth" to your application.

Comment: I do know the correct/desired order ahead of time prior to updating.

Comment: Right but you don't know the correct order before the insert, right?

Comment: I would know both the current sequence and the desired new sequence for all records. I'm only inquiring about updates and not inserts. But I'm curious, is your interpretation of unique constraints that their values can only be written once and never changed?

Comment: No.  I was just trying to clarify that you don't know the right values before the records are inserted for the first time.  So they have to be inserted with bad values and then later you must come back and do an update.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking about inserting since that is beyond the scope of my question, but for the sake of argument, I would insert new records at the end of the existing sequence (e.g. `MAX(SEQUENCE)+1`). If the user doesn't want it at the end, they can move it around and I'm back to the original question.